# Diagnose `DllNotFoundException` for native library in a linux docker container

Tags: .net, linux, docker, native, librdkafka

I have a dotnet app that depends on the [librdkafka-redist nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/librdkafka.redist/). I want to run this app in a docker container based on an alpine image, built for the linux-arm64 platform.

At runtime I see:

```
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Failed to load the librdkafka native library.
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.TrySetDelegates(List`1 nativeMethodCandidateTypes)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.LoadLinuxDelegates(String userSpecifiedPath)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.Initialize(String userSpecifiedPath)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2..ctor(ProducerBuilder`2 builder)
   at Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder`2.Build()
```

The library appears to be packaged correctly; if I shell into a container I see this:

```
$ ls /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native
librdkafka.so
```

but I can also tell that I'll have problems because alpine doesn't come packaged with glibc support:

```
$ ldd /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so
    /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb4158000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb4158000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb4158000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb4158000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb4158000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so)
Error relocating /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
...
```

I can use the alpine [gcompat](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) package and `patchelf` to apparently resolve some of these (slightly anonymised Dockerfile):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine

RUN apk add patchelf
RUN apk add binutils
RUN apk add gcompat

RUN    adduser --disabled-password \
        --gecos "" \
        --no-create-home \
        --uid 10028 \
        myuser

USER myuser

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser . app/

RUN patchelf --remove-needed ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so && \
    patchelf --add-needed libgcompat.so.0 /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so

ENV COREHOST_TRACE=1

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "app/MyApp.dll" ]
```

at which point I *think* I've resolved my native dependency problems:

```
$ ldd /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so
    /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb5290000)
    libgcompat.so.0 => /lib/libgcompat.so.0 (0xffffb4d5b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb5290000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb5290000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb5290000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0xffffb5290000)
    libucontext.so.1 => /lib/libucontext.so.1 (0xffffb4d49000)
    libobstack.so.1 => /usr/lib/libobstack.so.1 (0xffffb4d36000)
```

but I still get `DllNotFoundException` at runtime. As I set `COREHOST_TRACE=1` I can see that

```
Adding runtimeTargets native asset runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so rid=linux-arm64 assemblyVersion= fileVersion=0.0.0.0 from librdkafka.redist/1.9.2
...
Chose linux-arm64, so removing rid (win-x86) specific assets for package librdkafka.redist/1.9.2 and asset type native
Chose linux-arm64, so removing rid (win-x64) specific assets for package librdkafka.redist/1.9.2 and asset type native
Chose linux-arm64, so removing rid (osx-x64) specific assets for package librdkafka.redist/1.9.2 and asset type native
Chose linux-arm64, so removing rid (osx-arm64) specific assets for package librdkafka.redist/1.9.2 and asset type native
Chose linux-arm64, so removing rid (linux-x64) specific assets for package librdkafka.redist/1.9.2 and asset type native
...
Reconciling library librdkafka.redist/1.9.2
Parsed native deps entry 0 for asset name: librdkafka from package: librdkafka.redist, library version: 1.9.2, relpath: runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so, assemblyVersion , fileVersion 0.0.0.0
...
Processing native/culture for deps entry [librdkafka.redist, 1.9.2, runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so]
  Considering entry [librdkafka.redist/1.9.2/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
    Relative path query /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so (skipped file existence check)
    Probed deps dir and matched '/app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/librdkafka.so'
Adding to native path: /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/
...
Property NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES = /app/runtimes/linux-arm64/native/:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.11/:
```

before it fails at startup.

So I think I've a) ascertained that the framework is aware (and hopefully attempting) to load the native library I think it is and b) ascertained that there are no missing dependencies that would mean the library can't be loaded.

Are there any more processes or steps I can go through to further diagnose what's going on? I *think* there are a [series of dependencies](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Dependencies) that `ldd` isn't showing me -- on `openssl`, `zlib` etc which might be the problem, for example?

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue? I'm having that same error with that same kafka library. It started about 3 weeks ago for me.

Comment: We were at version 1.7.0. We updated it to version 2.0.2 and that somehow solved the issue. No idea why there was an issue out of a sudden. We had been using 1.7.0 for a year.

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually solve this one. I used `strace` to examine exactly what the process was looking for, and found that it was looking for a library named `alpine-librdkafka.so` rather than the `librdkafka.so` indicated in the exception.

Some digging later and I found that `Confluent.Kafka` is actually switching internally on the distribution and looking for a file named for the distribution. Unfortunately, in the release we were using there was no `alpine-librdkafka.so` arm64 build.

We've added a build from source to our pipeline, and now all good. Incidentally, I believe the needed build was added around `1.9.0`, but upgrading for us was more complicated than just building and packaging the build we needed from the source.